# Sistema Web al iniciar Sesion se queda pantalla en blanco

Tags: php, servidor, appserv

Buen día, acudo a la plataforma para hacer esta pregunta, ya que, no encuentro información en algún otro sitio acerca de mi problema. Esperando saber si me pueden orientar.
Tengo un Sistema web el cual estuve programando en un equipo que me habían asignado en mi empresa, el sistema es Web y utilizo HTML, PHP, JavaScript para programarlo, para hacer pruebas utilice AppServ para tener los servicios de Apache y MySql en mi equipo y así hacer pruebas de conexión remota con los demás usuarios entrando al Sistema por medio de mi dirección IP.

### Me tuvieron que cambiar el equipo

En el nuevo equipo instalé AppServ de igual manera que en mi antiguo equipo y lo unico que hice fue Exportar e importar la base de datos del sistema al nuevo MySql y toda la carpeta de archivos del sistema dentro de la carpeta de `C:\AppServ\www\`. Al querer ingresar el sistema e iniciar sesion, la pantalla **se queda en blanco** y no puedo acceder a ninguna parte del sistema.

Les dejo estas capturas demostrando lo anterior dicho.
**El Sistema en mi Equipo Anterior:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Despues de iniciar Sesion:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**En el equipo nuevo:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Despues de iniciar Sesion en el nuevo equipo:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No estoy seguro si este sea el lugar para preguntar esto, pero de verdad necesito orientación con este asunto. **¿Me estoy perdiendo de algo? ¿Me hace falta algo mas?** Cualquier modificacion que tenga que hacer a la pregunta, estoy abierto con tal de solucionar este problema. Agradezco su atencion.

Comment: Revisa: 1) Si hay errores en la consola de *Herramientas de Desarrollo* del navegador. 2) Si te faltó copiar archivos ocultos. 3) Logs de apache.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, las primeras 2 opciones no son viables, no tengo archivos ocultos y en las herramientas de desarrollo no me aparecia ningun error. Pero en los logs de apache detecte que hay problemas con muchos de mis archivos del sistema, me marca "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file" y en todos aquellos marca que la ultima linea es la que tiene el error, algo de lo que me di cuenta es que esto solo pasa en los archivos donde utilizo bastante PHP (Consultas etc) En las que no, las muestra sin problemas.

Comment: Te recomiendo entonces imprimir los errores que estás ocultando, ocupa en un archivo global las siguientes líneas para conocer más detalles del error dentro de tu proyecto con: `ini_set("display_errors", 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` Después pega los resultados que obtuviste en orden de poder ayudarte más en específico con el problema.

Comment: Haz una comparación del `phpinfo()` ó del php.ini entre ambos equipos, existen algunas directivas que afectan el parseo.

Comment: Hola Marcos, Bienvenido! Si no tienes problemas con el inglés creo que quizá en https://serverfault.com haya más especializad@s listos para detectar qué te pasa. De todos modos, si tienes los phpinfo de las dos máquinas, como indica Sal, podrías incluir las diferencias en la pregunta para ayudarte mejor? También si puedes mirar qué error te da apache i pasárnoslo en la pregunta, creo que puede ayudar. Un saludo!

Comment: Compaeñeros, Muchisimas gracias por sus respuestas! En especial a @Sal que fue el que me hizo solucionar mi problema. Hice un phpinfo() en las 2 maquinas y en primera me di cuenta que la version de php no era la misma, en la nueva maquina habia instalado un AppServ con php7 mientras que mi maquina tenia php5, Reinstale AppServ pero una version antigua con php5 y mi Sistema ya se ejecuta sin ningun problema! Les agradezco a todos!